# MenuFlyout changes page colors (bug?)

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, c++-cx

My environment is: Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 using C++/CX and XAML.

I have a very simple MenuFlyout attached to a button that has a very odd behavior.  You can click it once then selected a MenuFlyoutItem, however if you click it a second time it inverts all the colors on the page (such as the background turns white, which was black).

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55" Width="434" FontSize="25">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DataContext.EmployeeList[0].PayFrequency, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout Placement="Top">
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="WeeklyOption" Text="Weekly" Click="WeeklyOption_Click"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="BiWeeklyOption" Text="Bi-Weekly" Click="BiWeeklyOption_Click"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="MonthlyOption" Text="Monthly" Click="MonthlyOption_Click"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="BiMonthlyOption" Text="Bi-Monthly" Click="BiMonthlyOption_Click"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

as far as I can tell I'm not messing with any Styles or any colors anywhere.

Comment: Do you happen to have this line in your code behind?
this.DataContext = this;?
If you do then try to remove it and see if the condition goes away.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder that did fix it, but now none of my bindings work... so whats going on here because I'm confused.  Also is there a another fix to this so that my bindings do work?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Then you must make new class as viewmodel, move all bindings to it and set it as DataContext.